# SSRS 2005 find name of column with max value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, unpivot

The column on the far right is what I'm trying to add to my report. Is this possible to do without modifying the query to use something like Unpivot?

```
Step X      Step W      Step A     Step B     Step Y     Last Step
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1/21/2013   1/24/2013   1/3/2013   1/5/2013   1/7/2013   Step W
```

This is a step in the right direction, but it appears to only work in SSRS 2008: http://www.bigator.com/2012/04/26/spothighlight-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-each-row-in-matrix-report-in-ssrs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UNPIVOT` function and a `CROSS APPLY` to get this:

```
;with cte as
(
  select col, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([Step X], [Step W], [Step A], [Step B], [Step Y])
  ) unpiv
) 
select [Step X], 
  [Step W], 
  [Step A], 
  [Step B], 
  [Step Y],
  d.col LastStep
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select c1.col
  from cte c1
  inner join
  (
    select max(value) MaxDate
    from cte
  ) c2
    on c1.value = c2.maxdate
) d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a189/10)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Looks like I'll be using unpivot after all. Thanks!

Comment: @Kon_ `UNPIVOT` is great when you have data that is not normalized.

Comment: This seems to have issues when different records have a date in common: [SQL Fiddle with example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23f34/1). Any way around that?

Comment: @Kon_ you should post a new question with the new details.