# Select column name of max date from each row in SQL/SSRS 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

How can I add the 'Last Step' column on the far right to a report in SSRS? Essentially, I need the name of the column that contains the most recent date from that row. Actual data will be a few thousand rows, each with ~15 dates.

```
Name      Step X      Step W      Step A      Step B      Step Y     Last Step
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John      1/21/2013   1/24/2013   1/3/2013    1/27/2013   1/7/2013   Step B
Sally     1/22/2013   1/24/2013   1/12/2013   1/1/2013    1/5/2013   Step W
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/916c1/1) with simple example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of doing this by modifying the query from your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902909/ssrs-2005-find-name-of-column-with-max-value). This just adds the `name` into the result so you can get the `max(date)` for each name:

```
;with cte as
(
  select name, col, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([Step X], [Step W], [Step A], [Step B], [Step Y])
  ) unpiv
) 
select t.name, 
  [Step X], 
  [Step W], 
  [Step A], 
  [Step B], 
  [Step Y],
  d.col LastStep
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select c1.col
  from cte c1
  inner join
  (
    select name, max(value) MaxDate
    from cte
    group by name
  ) c2
    on c1.value = c2.maxdate
    and c1.name = c2.name
  where t.name = c1.name
) d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/916c1/19)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way without using dynamic sql (since this is for reporting services):

```
SELECT T.*, C.ColName
FROM yourtable T
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM (SELECT 'Step X', [Step X]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'Step W', [Step W]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'Step A', [Step A]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'Step B', [Step B]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'Step Y', [Step Y]) X(ColName,ColValue)
             ORDER BY ColValue DESC) C
```

and [the fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/916c1/11).

Answer (score 0):

For Posterity's sake, here is a modified version of bluefeet's answer to a similar question, and [the fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/916c1/16).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY value DESC) AS Rank
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      from yourtable
      unpivot
      (
        value
        for col in ([Step X], [Step W], [Step A], [Step B], [Step Y])
      ) unpiv
    ) X
)
SELECT  yt.[Step X]
      , yt.[Step W]
      , yt.[Step A]
      , yt.[Step B]
      , yt.[Step Y]
      , c1.col
FROM yourtable yt
JOIN cte c1
ON   yt.Name = c1.Name
AND  c1.Rank = 1
```